# How to use the RN measure function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to use the [measure](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback) function from RN?

I want to find the exact location and dimensions of the following image:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Image, View } from 'react-native';

class TestView extends Component {

  measureWelcome() {
     this.refs.welcome.measure(this.logWelcomeLayout);
   }

 logWelcomeLayout(ox, oy, width, height, px, py) {
  console.log("ox: " + ox);
  console.log("oy: " + oy);
  console.log("width: " + width);
  console.log("height: " + height);
  console.log("px: " + px);
  console.log("py: " + py);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Image
        source={require('../../assets/5.jpg')}
        style={{height:200, width:200}}
        ref="welcome"
      />
    </View>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.measureWelcome}>
        <Text> Click Me</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
  </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TestView;
```

So when I click `Click me` I get the error:

[image]

So, do I use the `measure` on the `View` or the `Image`? I was not able to find much information about it. What I want to do is find te information of the image and send it to another view? Can I do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because measureWelcome not know `this` context that has `refs.welcome`. So you must bind `this` context by change this code

**From**

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.measureWelcome}>
```

**To**

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.measureWelcome.bind(this)}> // OR
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.measureWelcome()}>
```

More info about binding `this` context I recommend to read [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Ignorance is not a bliss. Thank you.